# Is FreeBSD's UNIX Filesystem (UFS) best suited having a microSD storage?

Tags: freebsd, ufs

Is FreeBSD's UNIX Filesystem (UFS) best suited having a microSD storage? I have a Raspberry Pi SOC and microSD is where my FreeBSD is installed and at the same time, storage of my database data and other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UFS is certainly simple to configure, but doesn't offer as much protection for your data as say, ZFS does.  I run my Raspberry Pi on ZFS.  Even with a single-device VDEV, having the ZFS check-summing protection is convenient, and also the ZFS snapshots are handy both for system upgrades and easy integration into my existing ZFS-based backup system.  With a sufficiently large SD card, setting `copies=2` will give data redundancy that is better than single device, although not as good as a multi-device VDEV.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks @Jim L., need to check that ZFS. By the way, my Raspberry Pi is 3B model, do you think its hardware specifications are sufficient?

Comment: Mine is a Pi 4b with 8G RAM.